# jQuery works in script but not in console

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, webpack

I have one script that requires jQuery and it works fine when loaded in my browser, but when I want to use jQuery in my browser console for testing it seems to not be loaded. Why is this happening?
I'm using webpack for manage js files.

My script file "manage_users.js":

```
import 'jquery';
console.log("Manage users js is working!");
$('#usr').val('hello');
```

That works nice, when I load the page the input #usr is loaded with 'hello' value.

But if I go to browser dev tools and I try to change the value with jquery as:

```
$('#usr').val('new value');
```

it doesn't work. The error in the console is:

```
VM3115:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:11
```

It seems like jquery is not loaded in the browser console but it is loaded in my script because it works perfectly.

Comment: sometimes `$` var is removed from globals (when `jQuery.noConflict()` is called for example). If it's the case, unsing `jQuery` instead of `$` in the console should work. If not, i don't know what it is

Comment: I think you're trying to access an element that does not support a `val()` method or which does not exist

Comment: @Ionut the element is a simple input text, and it exists of course, and also support val() because I modified his value in my js file...

Comment: What result do you get if you use `document.getElementById('usr').value`?

Comment: it works, but i'm interested in jquery methods

Comment: If you type `console.log($)` what do you get?

Comment: `function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }` @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: That's not jQuery. The issue is because the `$` variable has been overwritten by another library. You'll need to determine which one that is, and change it - although that may have further effects.

Comment: [console output](https://gyazo.com/45f32c67f8112c5122df41d42624a220)

Comment: Yeah, that confirms it. `$` is 100% not jQuery, as `$('#usr').value` would throw an error if it was

Comment: I'm only using bootstrap and jquery. And my js file uses jquery and works as expected. But maybe is webpack the reason?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I tend to disagree, it could be a modified version of jQuery. I would suggest replacing the current version with another one and see what happens.

Comment: True, although unlikely.